# Integral is always less than over some domain?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm still trying to piece together how this works, but I was looking at the contraction theorem. Now, if I understand correctly, then, the integral operator is a contraction on continuous functions, over some domain with some type of constraints.

Does this mean $||\int_a^{b} f(x) || \leq ||f(x)||$ for a real variable $x$? Or are there any implications like this?

Comment: The operator $f\mapsto \int_a^b f(x)dx$ isn't a contraction because the output is a real number, not a continuous function. You do have $|\int_a^bf(x)dx|\leq\int_a^b|f(x)|dx\leq (b-a)\sup_{[a,b]}|f(x)|$, though.

Comment: A general form is Minkowski's integral inequality: $\|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx\|_{L^p} \leq \int_{a}^{b}\|f(x)\|_{L^p}\,dx$.